# Connecting CMOS sensor to (far away) PCB: understanding cable length

Tags: cables, transmission-line, lvds

The problem is a bit complex due to the number of unknown parameters and my inexperience. I need a way to determine how far I can put the PCB from the sensor without problems in the transmission of data.

Situation: I have a CMOS sensor and a PCB. The PCB will control the CMOS sensor and it will provide clock, configuration (using I2C), bias (3.3V/3.5V) and will readout the sensor (LVDS outputs, matching of 100 Ohm required on the PCB).

My main concern right now are the LVDS signals. They are clocked at 175 MHz (but we might be able to clock them slower, in the 20-40 MHz range).

**The problem: the receiving PCB might be located as far as 70 cm. I am trying to understand if the sensor can, in fact, drive such long cables without problems.**

Notice: the type of cable carrying the signals and power has not been decided yet. My guess is that we will use shielded twisted pairs, but I cannot be 100% sure right now.

Since I am not an expert in transmission lines, I tried to study the problem a bit. This is what I came up with, so far:

1) The parameters to consider for this problem are:

- the frequency of the signal
- the fact that it is a differential line
- the fact that it is a point-to-point connection
- the noise margin (which, I assume, is the same thing as the jitter...?)
- the type of cable

2) Wikipedia, under transmission line, states:

> A common rule of thumb is that the cable or wire should be treated as
>   a transmission line if the length  is greater than 1/10 of the
>   wavelength

Just to make a simple example using 3 frequencies, this would mean:

- f=20 MHz, Wavelength = 14.98 m, Cable 70 cm --> no issue
- f=40 MHz, Wavelength = 7.49 m, Cable 70 cm --> could be an issue
- f=175 MHz, Wavelength = 1.71 m, Cable 70 cm --> definitely an issue (this could be an issue even if the length were to be reduced down to 10 cm ??)

Is there something that I am not considering and that I should know, about the system?

Could you point me in the right direction to be able to obtain a reasonable answer to the problem?

NB1: I don't think that it would be possible to make a test, since the drivers are embedded in the sensor and I don't have them available on another IC.

EDIT1: Corrected mistake in the wavelength numbers.

EDIT2: In case someone stumbles on this question.

I found the following TI document: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snla187/snla187.pdf

On page 10 the money-plot shows that, in fact, at this speed and cable length, transmission is not problematic. This has been confirmed by talking to some local experts.

Regarding the cable type: is using shielded twisted pairs, there should be absolutely no problem. If using a flat cable, it would be good practice to put the 2 differential lines close together and isolated with ground cables around.

Comment: What does the sensor's data sheet tell you about its ability to drive this cable?

Comment: @Andyaka it tells me nothing because there is no data sheet :) The sensor is being designed right now; I am in contact with the designer, so I can ask him directly questions, but I would like to have an idea of what to ask first, and why!

Comment: If the interface is LVDS, you should have no problem with a 30 cm interface length, provided the impedances are matched (the same, +/- 10 10%) throughout the interface, and there is the standard (for LVDS) 100 ohm parallel termination at the destination.

Comment: Also, you need to consider the edge rate of your signals, not just the clock or data rate, when determining the frequency content you have to pass.  If you're unfamiliar with designing high speed interfaces, I suggest you look at one of the many LVDS app notes out there, like this one from TI:  http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snla187/snla187.pdf.

Comment: [Wavelength](https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators/frequency-to-wavelength) (in meters) \$\lambda = \frac{c}{f}\$ where \$c\$ is the speed of light (299,792,458 m/s), so a 20MHz lambda/10 = 1.499m, 40MHz = 0.75m, and 175MHz = 171.3cm

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in my copy-paste! I will update the correct number!